# Help needed computing the covariant derivative on one forms.

Tags: differential-geometry

This is probably a fairly standard thing to prove, but I'm having some trouble.

Given the four properties that the covariant derivative must satisfy on arbitrary tensors, the only one I can see being applicable to computing the covariant derivative of a one form is the one that says the covariant derivative commutes with the trace operator on any pair of indices.

So if I wanted to compute $\nabla _{\partial_{i}}dx^{j}$ at $p$ do I just find a mixed tensor $F$ such that $tr F = dx^{j}$ (e.g. $F^{i}_{jk} = 1/N$) at $p$ and use $$\nabla _{\partial_{i}}dx^{j} = tr(\nabla _{\partial_{i}}F)$$

If so, I'm having some trouble because I'm still running into the covariant derivative of a one form on the right hand of the above equation after expanding it. Perhaps the left side also will show up after on the right side again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use that

$$tr \left(dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = \delta^i_j$$

Note that $\delta^i_j$ is a constant function, so $\nabla_{\partial _k} \delta^i_j  =0$. Using the Leibniz rule and the fact that $\nabla$ commute with contractions,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}0 &= \nabla_{\partial_k} \left(dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = tr\left(\nabla_{\partial_k} dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) +tr \left( dx^i \otimes \nabla_{\partial_k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)\\
&= tr\left(\nabla_{\partial_k} dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) +tr \left( dx^i \otimes \Gamma_{kj}^l\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\right)\\
&= tr\left(\nabla_{\partial_k} dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) +   \Gamma_{kj}^l\delta^i_l \\
&= tr\left(\nabla_{\partial_k} dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) +   \Gamma_{kj}^i
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So we have

$$\nabla_{\partial_k} dx^i = -\Gamma_{kj}^i dx^j$$